# How JavaScript import works when a folder path is given?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Even after seeing sample React code online, I still couldn't understand the `import` method.

In my entry point of "index.tsx", there is the following import statement; however, I can't find "App" or "ThemeProvider" in ./components

```
import { App, ThemeProvider } from './components';
```

But instead of this, when I see "components/index.ts" it says:

```
export * from './common';
export * from './pages';
export * from './layout';
```

Is there some logic behind this?? How/where is this import path defined? Does "components/index.ts" have some special way of working?

Here are my directory structures:

```
├── components
│   ├── common
│   ├── index.ts
│   ├── layout
│   └── pages
├── constants
│   ├── external-links.ts
│   ├── faq-entries.ts
│   ├── index.ts
│   └── page-size.ts
├── index.css
├── index.tsx
├── logo.svg
├── react-app-env.d.ts
├── setupProxy.js
└── types
    ├── faq.ts
    ├── index.ts
    └── page.ts
```

Comment: `./components` is `./components/index.ts` which re-exports from the other files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `import { App, ThemeProvider } from './components'` and since you are not specifying a file, the `resolver` looks automatically for a `index.js` or `index.ts` inside the folder. Then this code

```js
export * from './common';
export * from './pages';
export * from './layout';
```

is exporting all your `export` form the listed files.